# Dump contents of variable to file while script is running in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, interrupt

I have a lot of files in a directory:

```
$ ls
file000001
file000002
# ... truncated ...
file999999
```

I am calculating the md5sum of the files like this and finally dumping it to a file:

```bsh
hashes=''
for file in $(ls); do
  hashes+=$(md5sum $file)
  hashes+="\n"
done

echo "$hashes" > hashes.txt
```

Now, I would like to press Ctrl + C while the execution of the script is within the `for` loop and have the contents of `hashes` dumped to the hashes.txt file. Is this possible?

(Yes, I can append the md5sum to `hahes.txt` every time the md5sum of each file is calculated but I intend to do it this way (as shown above).)

*Note that the example code above is terrible. I actually used md5sum as an example; I am doing some other stuff. The intention of my question is actually to find out how to make Ctrl + C work.*

Comment: I understand that this was not the point of the Q, but FYI `md5sum` does always [line buffer](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/md5sum.c;h=e41fb24bef06e6d1fcec0ba328e3c2cc0dfce2b5;hb=88c32fa68ee7057744bfb6d41f6e8eb68801306f#l880) its output, so simply `md5sum f1 f2 f3 huge-f4 > list` will leave you with the sums of `f1`, `f2` and `f3` in `list` if you press ^C while it's processing `huge-f4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trap break INT` before your loop:

```
hashes=
trap break INT
for file in *; do
  hashes+=$(md5sum -- "$file")$'\n'
done
trap - INT

echo "$hashes" > hashes.txt
```

I've corrected some dubious stuff in your script (`$(ls)`, `"\n"`).

FWIW, such a "nonlocal break" doesn't work in `mksh` or `yash`, but it does in `bash`, `dash`, `zsh` and `ksh93`.

Comment: why would that be "safer"? if you have any _technical_ objections, please put up and I'll include them in the answer, and if they're serious enough I'll just delete the whole thing. Notice that this Q is tagged [bash] and my solution was _explicitly_ meant as a simpler alternative to the code duplication and logic meandering that doing stuff in traps (as in the 1st answer) mean.

Comment: I meant "safer" in the sense of supporting other shells, I didn't say there was anything wrong with it on Bash. I should have said "more portable", sorry. Also, as I said, I didn't see the other answer (but I also didn't see you refer to that solution)

Answer (score 3):

```
trap ctrl_c INT

ctrl_c() {
    echo "$hashes" > hashes.txt
    exit 0
}
```

BTW, I would not use `ls` to get the list of file, but something like `for file in *; do`.

Comment: Consider using `printf` in place of `echo` for outputting variable data.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use the output of `ls` as input to another program.  It doesn't work (for any definition of "work" that includes the concepts of reliability or safety), and there is **never** any need to do so because the shell's globbing (i.e. wildcard expansion) does the job you are trying to do by mis-using `ls`.  See [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).

If you must do something similar, use `find ... -exec {} +` or `find ... -print0 | xargs -0r ...` rather than `ls` - either of them will actually work, and work safely no matter what characters are in the filenames.

Your `for` loop should be written as:

```
for file in *; do
  ...
done
```

You don't even need a `for` loop unless you are going to do something else with each `$file` within the loop.

Here are some alternative ways to do what your for loop does, by storing the output of `md5sum` into an array called `hashes`, and then printing it:

1. using `printf`:

   ```
   $ hashes=( $( md5sum * ) )
   $ printf '%s  %s\n' "${hashes[@]}" > hashes.txt
   $ cat hashes.txt
   b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1  file.1
   26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510  file.2
   6d7fce9fee471194aa8b5b6e47267f03  file.3
   ```

   Note that there are two `%s` separated by two spaces in the `printf` format string.  This will produce the same output as `md5sum` itself.

   BTW, you can see how the entries are stored in the array with `typeset -p`:

   ```
   $ typeset -p hashes
   declare -a hashes=([0]="b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1" [1]="file.1"
   [2]="26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510" [3]="file.2"
   [4]="6d7fce9fee471194aa8b5b6e47267f03" [5]="file.3")
   ```

   The shell has split the output of `md5sum` into words (as defined by the value of the shell's `$IFS` variable) and put each "word" in a separate element of the array.
2. using `tee`:

   ```
   $ hashes=( $( md5sum * | tee hashes.txt) )
   $ cat hashes.txt
   b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1  file.1
   26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510  file.2
   6d7fce9fee471194aa8b5b6e47267f03  file.3
   ```

Knowing this, Lasse Kliemann's trap answer could be written as:

```
trap ctrl_c INT

ctrl_c() {
    printf '%s  %s\n' "${hashes[@]}" > hashes.txt
    exit 0
}
```

However, you don't even need a trap here.   `md5sum` with `tee` will do what you want - i.e. simultaneously populate `$hashes` AND the `hashes.txt` file.

Or, if you don't want to use an array:

```
$ for file in *; do
    hashes+="$(md5sum "$file" | tee -a hashes.txt)"$'\n'
  done

$ echo "$hashes"
b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1  file.1
26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510  file.2
6d7fce9fee471194aa8b5b6e47267f03  file.3
```

Here we're using `tee`'s `-a` (`--append`) option because we're running `md5sum` in a loop, and don't want each iteration to overwrite the `hashes.txt` file.

Note: This will always have an extra blank line at the end of the `$hashes` string, increasing the line count by 1.  This will not be the case when using an array.

Comment: For an answer that essentially contains just the same solution as another answer (the trap), this one sure has a lot of irrelevant filler. `for f in $(ls)` is obviously silly, but it's hardly even close to the main point _that was being asked about_. Using an array or `printf` doesn't really change things either (at least you didn't show how it would), and `tee` does exactly what they said they didn't want: fills the output file continuously.

Comment: did you see the part of the question where they explicitly say they don't want the continuous updating? _"Yes, I can append the md5sum to hahes.txt everytime the md5sum of each file is calculated but I intend to do it this way (as shown above)."_? As for challenging that, you didn't even say _why_ the continuous update would be better. And yes, I think that's pretty much a requirement for a frame challenge.

Comment: it's one thing to suggest an alternative solution, but to go off in another direction, ignoring the question that was asked, and claiming "it should be obvious" is just arrogant. Apart from passing that `"\n"` to `echo`, they get the same output as you did with their loop, and even that works if they have `xpg_echo` set. There's also no word splitting of the `md5sum` output in the original.

Comment: What's obvious to you, might not be obvious to everyone else. It's not just me reading your answer, there are potentially many others. Not too many yet, it says "viewed 41 times", but that's still a lot more than just me. In some cases arrays are more useful than singular strings, sure, but if all they want to do is collect the outputs of some command invocations, then no, I can't see the advantage of using one. I can't see a "simulation of an array" either, it's not like they're trying to index into that string to extract a particular line or anything like that.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. However, I was not looking for an alternate solution.

Comment: no problem. someone else who reads this might gain something useful from it.